# TXOP and Service Period in 802.11e

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, qos

I want to know what is TXOP and what is service period in 802.11n or 802.11e.

Is there any relation or difference between TXOP and SP

Thanks,
Devaa

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A TXOP is a transmission opportunity granted by the Access Point to the Station.

It is a given period of time during which the station can send as many frame as it wishes.

A service period is related to power saving. It's the period during which the Station listen before going back to sleep. It is initiated by the Station and allow the Access Point to send traffic destined to the Station that have been buffered.

In short :

TXOP , QoS mechanism, AP initiated, traffic from Station to AP

Service Period, Power saving mechanism, Station initiated, traffic from AP to Station

Comment: @devaa Don't forget to mark his answer as valid.